# unexpected character occurred when trying to parse json

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm getting the error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'"

My json file content is: `{ "employees": [] }`

My code:

```
var jsonStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentRootPath + "/Resources/Employees.json");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonStr))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonStr);
```

I've verified in the debugger that the jsonStr content is: `"{ \"employees\": [] }"`

Comment: Shouldn’t you be deserialising it to an Employee object type rather than a string?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: can you give an example? this is not directly an employee, it's an object that contains employee array

Comment: Paste your JSON into the link I provided. 99% of JSON issues with C# are solved by doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize your JSON `object` as a string. You need to make a class / struct with an `employees` field and deserialize it into that.

Or deserialize it into a dynamic object and navigate the tree manually.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting that employees is an array of string, try this

```
var json="{\"employees\": []}";
var jD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

List<string> employees=jD.Employees.ToList();

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("employees")]
    public string[] Employees {get; set;}
}
```

test

```
json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jD);
```

output

```
{"employees":[]}
```